# Sequelize - Query a table just by a value

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Currently, I'm using ExpressJS and Sequelize ORM to build a web app. I got stuck when I was trying to query a table when I realized that I need to query it just by a value (meaning, the value can be in one or another field).

Here is the specific Model.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('petRelation', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        sender: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'pets',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        receiver: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'pets',
                key: 'id'
            }
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        created_at: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            allowNull: false
        },
        updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        deleted_at: DataTypes.DATE
    }, {
        tableName: 'petRelation',
        paranoid: true,
        underscored: true
    });
};
```

In my application, there are Pets which can have a friend relationship between them. I am trying to list every relation a Pet has, meaning that a Pet's ID can be located either at the "sender" field, either at the "receiver" field.

I documented myself using the Sequelize docs, google search, stack search and I found nothing useful.

A normal query, for which I know the field where the Pet's Id resides in, will look like this.

```
db.pets.findAll({
    where: {
        sender: petID
    }    
})
```

If someone knows how to query a table just by value in Sequelize, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you can query a table just by value in any of its fields but if it's just two fields (sender and receiver) you can use an `or` operator like this:

```
db.pets.findAll({
    where: {
        $or:[{
            sender: petID
        },{
            receiver: petID
        }]

    }    
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it. I tried your solution and it worked like a charm. Marking your answer as correct.